# Adding Rollbar in a Heroku application without the Rollbar Heroku add-on

Tags: python, heroku, flask, rollbar

I am trying to add rollbar to my python flask application in Heroku.

**Pipfile**

```
Rollbar = "~=0.14.7"
```

**app.py**

```
import rollbar

rollbar_api_key = os.environ['ROLLBAR_API_KEY']

rollbar.init(rollbar_api_key)
rollbar.report_message('Rollbar is configured correctly')

try:
  b = a + 1
except:
  rollbar.report_exc_info()
```

But this is not working.

I am not able to add rollbar as an addon in Heroku since credit card details are required. Is it possible to add rollbar in heroku without the add-on?

**Update:**

Error:

```
app[web.1]: import rollbar
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rollbar'
```

Link to the app for which I am trying to add `Rollbar`:

https://github.com/glassechidna/fwdform2

Comment: does that mean you don't have any Rollbar account? or just not through the Heroku Addon?

Comment: @DenisCornehl I do have a Rollbar account. But I am not able to set up the Heroku add-on.

Comment: what kind of error are you seeing? when the API-Key is set I assume everything should work. 

Is this app.py only doing what you describe here? Or is it also running the server? 

Many logging/reporting libraries actually send the error in a thread in the background, so if the app is exiting too fast, it could get lost I believe

Comment: I am running a python flask app in Heroku. I am getting this error: `app[web.1]: import rollbar
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rollbar'`

Comment: Link to the app for which I am trying to add `Rollbar`: https://github.com/glassechidna/fwdform2

Comment: Thanks for the update! This looks like the python package is not installed. 

- have you added the rollbar package also to `Pipfile.lock`? 
- when you push/deploy your application, what does the log show you? Which packages are installed?

Comment: @DenisCornehl: Not sure how I can add it to Pipfile.lock. I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are seeing the error `ModuleNotFound`, it seems like the `rollbar` python package is not installed.

To add a new package to the project's `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` you have to use the `pipenv` package:

```
$ pip install pipenv 
 [...]
$ pipenv install rollbar 

Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing rollbar…
Adding rollbar to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✔ Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (0834c3)!

With pipenv you'll need the `pipenv install` command: 
, following for example the [pipenv guide here](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/#example-usage).
```

As you see in the output the command will update both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the ROLLBAR_API_KEY environment variable's value? When you add the Rollbar add-on, it sets that for you, but if you want to use Roller without using the add-on, you'll need to set that yourself. This can be done with `heroku config:set ROLLBAR_API_KEY=ABC123`.

Comment: I have manually configured it already. That is not the issue.